# Type wise summation and subtracting in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have two table of my store and working on Oracle. [Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16RPErEejPn7ibEp02w_-12KvaJ8yRV1T/view?usp=sharing) First table describe about my transaction in store, there are two types of transaction (MR & SR), MR means adding products in Store and SR means removing products from my storage. What I wanted to do get the final closing of my storage. After transaction final Quantity every products as shown in Image. I have tried many solution but can't finish it. so I could not show now. Please help me to sort this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use case as below to decrease and increase the quantity based on type and then group by Name and find the sum of quantity derived from the case statement to get your desired result.

```
select row_number() over (order by a.Name) as Sl,a.Name, sum(a.qntity) as qntity
from 
(select t2.Name,case when t1.type='MR' then t2.qntity else -(t2.qntity) end as qntity 
from table1 t1,table2 t2 where t1.oid=t2.table01_oid) a 
group by a.Name;
```

This query will provide result as below:

```
    SL NAME                 QNTITY
```

---

```
     1 Balls                            0
     2 Books                            6
     3 Pencil                          13
```